# Would scrolling of mouse be a hardware or a software interrupt?

Tags: mouse, linux-device-driver, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I'm basically a computer science grad student and have developed an interest in device drivers and software-hardware interaction. I am assuming that clicking the mouse or pressing a key on the keyboard would be a hardware interrupt managed by a software event-handler for the programmer to interact with it, but I'm unable to figure out whether scrolling of mouse would be a hardware or a software interrupt. Also which type of interrupt is more costly to handle for the processor?

Comment: It depends. It might be software in some cases when driver is working in polling mode, it most probably would be a hardware interrupt. If you want to dive into this topic, you need to go through Linux kernel device driver model and read a lot of source code to get it right. Be aware that what you find for your specific device doesn't mean to be the same on other (mouse) devices.

Comment: @0andriy Could you give me a starting point as to where from can I start reading more about the kernel and it's source code?

Comment: Sounds like Google.COM ?
Not really, you may start from understanding what hw interface mouse is using and what driver is behind it.

Comment: I do not think op needs google.com as an advice. Myself is interested in this and want to know which class of driver sources do I need to look at, whether kernel is involved, what kext is of interest, etc. If you cannot offer that just say 'I don't know'. Please do not throw google out as an answer to that.